# Adding new element by clicking Dynamically added button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script for adding dynamic  content inside containerDivs. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/srFkJ/2/

This div element structure is added in multiple places in the HTML page. Please click First and Second buttons in the fiddle to see this.

The dynamic script adds a button named “View Recipients” to the HTML. When any of the “View Recipients” button is clicked, a new Div element (childHTML  in fiddle code) need to be added to the corresponding logRow div (yellow background). How can we do this?

Comment: Thanks to @DavidHedlund http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/srFkJ/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a live listener to the `.viewRecipientsButton`, which will trigger even for buttons that didn't exist when the listener was added

```
$('.viewRecipientsButton').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.logRow').append($(childHTML));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sJWHA/)

Note that `live` is deprecated these days, but since you're including jQuery 1.4.1 in your document, I suppose this is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks. What can I use instead of "live" if I am migrating to a newer version?

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you should switch to `.on`. `$(container).on('click', '.viewRecipientsButton', listener);` Note that `container` has to be a container that does exist when the listener is added, and it should preferrably be one as close to the button as possible. From jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.7, use `delegate`, with almost exactly the same syntax: `$(container).delegate('.viewRecipientsButton', 'click', listener);`